# QGIS Processing Modeller reusing output as input for next step

Tags: qgis, modelbuilder, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I would like to run the *Sample Points* algorithm over 20+ rasters, reusing the *sampled result* as the input for the next iteration of *Sample Points*.

At the moment I am achieving the wanted result by using the Batch Interface and calculating the output of *Sampled Points* by using an expression like:

```
'Sampled_' || @row_number || '.gpkg'
```

And doing similar thing for the input of *Sample Points* (apart from first row where original sample point file is referenced):

```
'Sampled_' || to_string( @row_number -1 ) || '.gpkg'
```

Is there a better way of doing the same workflow without creating 20+ temporary *.gpkg* files?